# implementacion de sweet alert en un @html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Necesito que mi `@Html.ActionLink();` me ejecute un `onclick()` y luego me ejecute el controlador que le mando como sobrecarga esto es lo que tengo.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteMunicipality", new { id = item.MunicipalityId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger", onClick = "swal({   title: 'Are you sure?',   text: 'You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',   type: 'warning',   showCancelButton: true,   confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',   confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',   closeOnConfirm: false }, function(){   swal('Deleted!', 'Your imaginary file has been deleted.', 'success');});" })`
```

Comment: debería funcionar así como está.Te da algún problema? no se está ejecutando?

Comment: Pues amigo lo que pasa es que cuando le doy click al botón me funciona el onclick pero es solo como un pantallaso rapido, es decir no hace bien la tarea solo muestra la alerta pero muy rápido y debería de quedarse un rato porque tiene alguna funcionalidad de botones, pero pasa de largo y hay mismo se ejecuta el controllador

Comment: puedes intentar atrapar el click con jquery en vez de utilizar el onclick.

Comment: puedes darme algun link de referencia porfa?

Comment: Sí. perdona, te doy una mano ni bien termine acá en el trabajo.

Comment: Gracias amigo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el ActionLink() realiza un submit al servidor lo que hayas ejecutado en el cliente no tendrias ninguna validez, lo que recomendaria es que trabajes todo en codigo cliente.

Podrias definir un link simple en html y asignarle jquery para realizar la accion

```
<a id="link1" valor="@item.MunicipalityId" >Delete</a>

<script>
   $(function(){
      $("#link1").click(function(){

           //aqui realizas la accion que necesites

           var params = {
              id: $(this).attr('valor');
            };

           $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "DeleteMunicipality")',
             data: params,
             datatype: "html",
             success: function (data) {
                 //codigo
             }
           });

      });
   });
</script>
```

La idea es que ejecutes la accion que necesites en codigo cliente y lugo usando jquery con $.ajax invoques el action del controller

[Posting Data With jQuery AJAX In ASP.NET Razor Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages)

[jQuery Ajax GET and POST calls to Controller's Method in MVC](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html)

Comment: Amigo en la parte de succes no iria nada o si ?

Comment: sino necesitas hacer nada a la vuelta de la invocacion del action puede quitar el succes  de $.ajax

Comment: ya pero a la hora de ejecutar me dice function is not defined, y a la etiqueta a hay que agrégale el href para poder darle click. que procede?

Comment: al parecer no me reconoce la libreria de jquery, que esta en el _layaout

Comment: podrias usar el developer tools del browser al cual accedes con F12 para ver si hay un error de javascript, valida que '<script>' lo defines correctamente referenciando a jquery